# Split and clean multiple length strings in a column to multiple columns using R script

Tags: r

I have data in the following format:

```
test1 <- data.frame(value = c('25.5 (5%);  39.65 (23%)', '28.15(5%) and 55.66 (34%) and 33.26   (14%)', '45   56.9565', '95.6666 (55%)  89.2343(90%)   51.56 (28%)'))
test2 <- data.frame(value = c('36.5', '55.658', '47.8', '51.562'))
```

I need to split the values in column test1 into three columns (col1, col2 and col3) and then compare and highlight the value in the column (test2) that is within +/- 0.1 of the value in one of the three columns (col1, col2 and col3) as shown in the image below.

Please suggest on how to proceed with this.

```
col1    col2    col3    test2
25.5    39.65           36.5
28.15   55.66   33.26   **55.658**
45      56.9565         47.8
95.6666 89.2343 51.56   **51.562**
```

[string split (and cleaned) into columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et5O7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsub` with `read.table` to extract the 'value' column into three columns

```
df1 <- read.table(text=gsub("\\([^)]+\\)|[A-Za-z]+", "", test1$value), 
                    header=FALSE, fill=TRUE, col.names = paste0("col", 1:3))
```

and `cbind` it with the 'test2'

```
df2 <- cbind(df1, test2)
df2
#    col1    col2  col3  value
#1 25.5000 39.6500    NA   36.5
#2 28.1500 55.6600 33.26 55.658
#3 45.0000 56.9565    NA   47.8
#4 95.6666 89.2343 51.56 51.562
```

#### Update

With the new data

```
cbind(read.table(text=gsub("\\([^)]+\\)|[A-Za-z]+|[;,]\\s*", "", 
   test1$value), header=FALSE, fill=TRUE, col.names = paste0("col", 1:3)), test2)
#    col1    col2  col3  value
#1 25.5000 39.6500    NA   36.5
#2 28.1500 55.6600 33.26 55.658
#3 45.0000 56.9565    NA   47.8
#4 95.6666 89.2343 51.56 51.562
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I was breaking my head last 3 days to solve this and you solved this in 3 seconds. Great!  I very much appreciate your skill and your kindness.

Comment: What if there was a semicolon or a comma after the bracket like for example:  test1 <- data.frame(value = c('25.5 (5%);  39.65 (23%)', '28.15(5%); and 55.66 (34%) and 33.26   (14%)', '45   56.9565', '95.6666 (55%)  89.2343(90%)   51.56 (28%)'))? When I parse this using the method suggested by you, semicolon goes in to a separate column. What am I missing here?

Comment: @RanonKahn  In that case, `cbind(read.table(text=gsub("\\([^)]+\\)|[A-Za-z]+|[;,]\\s*", "", test1$value),  header=FALSE, fill=TRUE, col.names = paste0("col", 1:3)), test2)`